# How can I show 'Back'/'Forward' buttons in the Android Studio 3.0.1 IDE | Iguana 2023.2.1?

Tags: android, ide, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-girafee, android-studio-lguana

It's quite annoying since upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.1 such that the "Back/Forward" buttons are not displayed in tool bar at the top in IDE any more.

I know, I can select "Navigation-> Back/Forward", but obviously, it's very annoying if you Back/Forward frequently; also, the shortcut by keys are not looking a good choice for my situation. I want to show those two buttons in the IDE, or say, I prefer to click around with *mice*!

Digging around the settings in IDE and seemed not able to figure out how to achieve this *simple* goal.

To me, removing those simple buttons dramatically reduces the usability of the IDE!

Comment: FWIW, they are showing up for me, to the right of the find/paste options. Right click over the empty space to the end of a row of toolbar buttons, choose "Customize Menus and Toolbars", look in the Main Toolbar, and see if you can add them back.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am totally lost. Can't right click anywhere in the tool bar at the top in the IDE. Can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In my **Android Studio 3.0.1** installation, the buttons you seek are already in the main toolbar (see where the red arrow points):

[image: navigation buttons in AS 3.0.1 main toolbar]

To configure the contents of the toolbars, right-click over an open area in the toolbar panel and choose "Customize Menus and Toolbars..." from the context menu:

[image: AS 3.0.1 toolbar context menu]

That will bring up a dialog where you can see the contents of the main toolbar and manipulate those contents:

[image: Menus and Toolbars dialog]

In **Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13**:

Open View and then click Toolbar if it is unchecked. You will now get your toolbar with back and forward navigate buttons.

[image: View Menu]

Best of Luck!

Comment: This action - right-clicking on an empty part of the toolbar - makes the assumption that the toolbar is actually visible. In Android Studio 3.1.1 at least, you need to make sure 'Toolbar' is ticked in the View menu before the toolbar displayed in this answer is visible.

Without this, some of the controls will be visible to the right-hand side, but the blank space will not be right-clickable.

Comment: Works in Android Studio 3.1.3.

Comment: But not for 3.5.1.

Comment: For later versions of Android Studio see @MdNehaluddinHaider's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519698/211292

Answer (score 45):

Click on "View" option in android studio(in top bar) and then click on "Toolbar" option.

Comment: It was very frustrating trying to figure this out after having to reinstall AS. thank you

Answer (score 30):

For [Android Studio Giraffe](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-giraffe-release-notes) | 2022.3.1, you need to perform the below steps:

1. Goto the **Preferences/Settings**.
2. Choose **Appearance & Behaviour** from the left menu:

   [image]
3. Select **Menus and Toolbars** and then open **Navigate**:

   [image]
4. Select **Back** and **Forward** buttons and *drag and drop* it to **Main Toolbar Left** or **Right**:

   [image]
5. Press <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then press <kbd>OK</kbd> to get the buttons.

Comment: Have the same problem in Android Studio Hedgehog, 2023 and this still solves the issue. thank you!

Comment: works for me in lastest android studio version Hedgehog also

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clean explanations

Answer (score 17):

From Android Studio 4.0 you can go at the menu: View -> Appearance -> Toolbar

Answer (score 9):

For me it was simply going to the View tab and make sure Toolbar is checked. Voila! Friendly arrows back.
credit to @cro comment [how to show Back/Forward buttons in Android Studio 3.0.1 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369494/how-to-show-back-forward-buttons-in-android-studio-3-0-1-ide#comment86807030_49371856)

Answer (score 6):

In [Android Studio Giraffe](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-giraffe-release-notes) (2023) and enabled new UI. If someone facing issue, follow the below steps.

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *Menus and Toolbars*.

Add the navigation actions (Main Menu* → *Navigate* → *Back and Forward*) to *Main Toolbar Right* or *Main Toolbar Left*.

Comment: The first sentence is incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76807849/edit) it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, just go to View> Appearance> Make sue Toolbar is checked. This is as per AS version 3.6.3

Answer (score 2):

Eesy. View -> Appearance -> Toolbar. For Android Studio 4.2

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64112474/2227743 and other answers

Answer (score 2):

This is missing at least in [Android Studio Giraffe](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-giraffe-release-notes) | 2022.3.1 Beta 5. I hope they will add it in future updates. I added [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/287713653) to Google here in the Google issue tracker. Please upvote if you want that feature.

Now in **Giraffe**, the main toolbar is customizable in the new UI. You have to go to *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *Menus and Toolbars* → *Main Toolbar Left* and here you can see the <kbd>Back</kbd> and <kbd>Forward</kbd> button.

[image]

Comment: Brother i have added the icons but they are not clickable. Kindly tell me if you have the solution

Answer (score 1):

Simple step you can find in screenshot.

[image]

Just we need to enable toolbar

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Giraffe New Theme you can achieve "back" and "forward" button by following below steps :
Goto ToolBar --> right button --> Customize Toolbar --> Choose add action(+ icon) --> add action --> select Main Menu --> Navigate --> select "back" and "forward" buttons --> ok --> apply.

Then check your Toolbar, it will be reflected.

For ref : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html#add-toolbar-actions

Answer (score 0):

Let use shortcut, if you use `Ubuntu Linux`, go `setting` --> `keyboard` --> `navigation`, change shortcut `ctrl` + `alt` + `left/right` to other. Default on `AS` is `ctrl` + `alt` + `left`

Answer (score 0):

In [Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?_gl=1*1k1vjvr*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQjwncWvBhD_ARIsAEb2HW81H9Sl1GLYKtZWKb2R5dCQFPscCHOKcrdTZbZZUegJ4jyAZSLMdeUaAoIvEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)
Follow these steps:

1. Right click on toolbar
   [image]
2. Choose Add to Main Toolbar > Back / Forward option
   [image]
3. On click on Back / Forward action, buttons will appear in toolbar.
   [image]